# Undescriptive, indescriptive, nondescript or indescript?

Tags: single-word-requests, differences

I was hoping to use a word which means something is not descriptive.

(In this case it was an error message which provided too little information.  It just said "Operation Failed".)

My spellchecker complained when I tried to use the words *'undescriptive'* and *'indescriptive'*, and the definitions of *'nondescript'* and *'indescript'* did not sound quite right.

> So which is the best word to use to mean *"not descriptive"* or *"lacking description"*?
>
> And what are the difference or similarities between the four words I have mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

I would call that message ***inadequate***, but I don't think that's what you're looking for.  Instead, you might consider ***non-specific***, or ***ill-defined***.  Per the Oxford Living Dictionaries:

> ***[non-specific](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/non-specific)***
>
> **ADJECTIVE**
>
> 1. Not detailed or exact; general.
>
>    *‘the term ‘cohort’ implies a fairly large but non-specific number’*

and

> ***[ill-defined](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ill-defined)***
>
> **ADJECTIVE**
>
> Not having a clear description or limits; vague.
>
> *‘ill-defined concepts’*

Another option, if you really want a single, non-hyphenated word, might be ***incomplete***:

> ***[incomplete](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incomplete)***
>
> **ADJECTIVE**
>
> 1. Not having all the necessary or appropriate parts.
>
>    *‘incomplete carvings of cattle’*
>
>    1.1 Not full or finished.
>
>    *‘the analysis remains incomplete’*